# Asynchronously add events in backbone

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, backbone.js, backbone-events

In backbone, how do you asynchronously add events, based on other events. I want to allow click handlers on a certain set of buttons, but not until their containing button is clicked. Here's how I have things set up at the moment:

```
var ProductsView = Backbone.View.extend({


  events : {
        "click .filter-options-container" : "filterOptionContainerClick"
  },

  filterOptionContainerClick: function(e){
    $(e.currentTarget).addClass('active');
    //want to add an event to all .filter-options to allow them to trigger the filterOptionClick function when clicked
  },

  filterOptionClick: function(e){
    $('.filter-option').removeClass('active');
    $(e.currentTarget).addClass('active');
    $('.filter-options-container').removeClass('active');
  }

});

return ProductsView;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of adding `click` handlers for sub-buttons whenever the container is clicked, you can use another approach:

1. register sub-buttons' `click` handlers once with `events` map.
2. add boolean property to the View to store state of the container
   click
3. toggle that property in `filterOptionContainerClick` handler
4. depends on the value of the property, allow/disallow clicking on
   sub-buttons

So the code should look like this:

```
var ProductsView = Backbone.View.extend({

    events : {
        "click .filter-options-container" : "filterOptionContainerClick",
        "click .filter-options" : "filterOptionClick" // register sub-buttons' click handlers
    },
    initialize: function() {
        this.enabled = false; // state of the container click
    },

    filterOptionContainerClick: function(e){
        this.enabled = !this.enabled;
        if (this.enabled) $(e.currentTarget).addClass('active');
        else $(e.currentTarget).removeClass('active');
    },

    filterOptionClick: function(e){
        if (!this.enabled) return;
        $('.filter-option').removeClass('active');
        $(e.currentTarget).addClass('active');
        $('.filter-options-container').removeClass('active');
    }

});
```

Comment: @mheavers You could upvote this answer if it solve your problem